# Why Doesn't This text input abide by the styles I set to it

Tags: css

I have a text input with a set height and padding however the padding is not taking effect. And it gets even weirder. I created a js fiddle (linked below) and in the js fiddle it works fine however if I make a test page and open it directly in my browser (chrome on a mac) it disregards the padding. Please help I've tried everything I could think.

BTW. I'm testing this on **chrome for mac**
http://jsfiddle.net/Jebg3/

**UPDATE**

I've linked to a file where the issue is clear.

http://levihoch.com/tests/input.html

**UPDATE 2**

@truth suggested using the box-sizing property and it works perfectly in opera however it breaks in every version of IE. The updated page is here:
http://levihoch.com/tests/input.html?v=2

Comment: It looks fine to me if I compare the padding in http://jsfiddle.net/Jebg3/ to the padding in the frame http://fiddle.jshell.net/Jebg3/show/. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MathiasBynens I'm asking if he used a CSS reset on his page, I know jsFiddle uses a CSS reset and that might be the difference....

Comment: @Truth might be right. On the jsFiddle page, a CSS reset is included. See the “normalize CSS” checkbox. (Note: it uses a reset, not [`normalize.css`](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/)).

Comment: I removed the styles that normalize.css adds and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @mrsmee It’s not `normalize.css`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following property to your list of rules:

```
box-sizing: content-box;
```

For some reason Chrome applies "border-box" to it, which causes your `height: 13px;` to be calculated from the border, and not from the content.

**[Here's a great article on the subject, by Chris Coyer @ CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)**

Comment: I don't know, they weird thing is it doesn't happen on jsFiddle, but it does on your site. Maybe someone else can shed light on the subject

Comment: I just tested it in IE and it breaks in every version. Very weird, this has never happened to me before.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on the sample you posted, the `<style>` tag is in the incorrect place. Try placing it in the `<head>` tag of the document...

Comment: It usually doesn't matter, but I gave it a shot and I it didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: Just for validation purposes, it's good practice to place the tags in the correct place. :) Hope you get this sorted though...